# What was it she died of

Tags: inversion

> "What was it she died of, the clap?" (The Cuckoo's Calling, by Robert Galbraith)

It seems like the structure is: *what* is shifted from the position of the complement of *of*; and there's a subject verb inversion, from: `It was [she died of what]?` Is this right understanding?

Comment: This is sort of broken speech.  It's in quotes--how the character talks--presumably to try and sound a little uneducated, or casual.  *"What did she die of?  Was it the clap?"* would be more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What was it she died of,* the clap?

The example sentence is fine. The question portion (in *italics*) of it is in the form of an interrogative *it*-cleft.

Consider a simple declarative:

1. *She died of [the clap].*

and then, a possible *it*-cleft:

2. *It was [the clap](i) [(that) she died of __(i)].*

and now, convert the main clause into an *in situ* interrogative clause:

3. *It was **what**(i) [(that) she died of __(i)]?*

and now front the interrogative word:

4. ***What***(i) *was it [(that) she died of __(i)]?*

You will see that #4 is the same as the question portion of your original example:

> *What was it she died of,* the clap?

**ALTERNATIVELY:** It could also be looked at in a way similar to the way you were doing it.

Consider an *in situ* interrogative clause:

B1. *She died of **what?***

and then, into an *it*-cleft:

B2. *It was **what**(i) [(that) she died of __(i)]?*

and now front the interrogative word:

B3. ***What***(i) *was it [(that) she died of __(i)]?*

which again is the same as the question portion of your original example:

> *What was it she died of,* the clap?

So, you can do it either way. :)

Comment: +1 I like both your versions, but your second's the best imo. Less stages, more elegant :)

Comment: (Example New) “I think the reason she wanted to meet you so badly was because of (A) _what_ her mother had just told her,” Strike said. “Lady Bristow had taken a lot of Valium. I’m guessing she wanted to make the girl feel too bad to leave her, so she told Lula (B) _what_ Tony had said about John all those years before”

Comment: When it’s not a case of it-cleft (Example New), can ‘what’ be interpreted both ways as your reply? I mean: (i) what=the thing (or something) that; (ii) ‘what’ are shifted from in situ questions respectively: her mother had just told her _what_? ; Tony had said _what_ about John?

Comment: @Listenever For your first question: It sounds like you want to know if the "what" expressions in your examples are part of a fused-relative (NP) or an embedded question (subordinate interrogative clause). Such a topic/answer can sometimes be easy, and, many times, hard to figure out. If you want those examples looked into, then, perhaps open a new question thread specifically for it, for the answer post could end up being long. For related info, there's pages 1068-1073 ([1] to [16]). (I just re-read those pages to refresh my memory.)

Comment: @Listenever For your last (2nd) question: Your last two examples have the interrogative word *in situ,* and are fine. Those two examples involve two topics: *in situ* interrogative words, and echo questions. Both topics are found in the 2002 CGEL's "Conceptual index" in the back, under: "in situ" on pages 856, 873, 888, 910, 914, 973; "question -- echo" on pages 886-91, etc. The appropriate context is needed to support these types of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

She died of it = It killed her.
What was it?
What was it that killed her?
What was it she died of?

What was it you were saying?